# What does LOCK_NB mean in flock?

Tags: php, linux

What does `LOCK_NB` mean in the PHP `flock` command?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`LOCK_NB` means non-blocking.

Usually when you try to lock a file, your PHP script execution will stop. The call to `flock()` then *blocks* it from resuming. It does so until a concurrent lock on the accessed file is removed.

Mostly your process is the only one trying to lock the file, so the blocking call to `flock` actually returns instantly. It's only if two processes lock the very same file, that one of them will be paused.

The `LOCK_NB` flag however will make `flock()` return immediately *in any case*. In that setting you have to check the returned status to see if you actually aquired the lock. As example:

```
while ( ! flock($f, LOCK_NB) ) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

Would more or less emulate the behaviour of the normal blocking call. The purpose of course is to do something else / meaningful (not just wait) while the file is still locked by another process.

Comment: means if i do a `LOCK_EX ` on a file on script 1 , and at the same time script 2 is trying to read the file or do a `LOCK_EX` script 2 will wait till script 1 unlocks the file ? .

Comment: so when am writing output to cache , but when i need to update the data , and rewrite the cache , 100 `LOCK_EX` users simultaneously wait for the `LOCH_SH` to finish then while these 100 `lock_ex` write , more `lock_sh` are waiting till my server goes boooom !!! . can LOCK_NB solve it ?

Comment: No, it's not a solution for that. And it doesn't sound like much of a cache if you have that many concurrent write requests.

Comment: According to http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php, you're not supposed to use LOCK_NB on its own, but in combination with one of the lock types -- example from the that manual page:

`if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo 'Unable to obtain lock';
    exit(-1);
}`

Comment: What happens you use LOCK_NB on Windows?